# Get all parameters from JSP page without request.getParameters()

Tags: java, jsp

I know we could get all parameters by request.getParameters(), but can we do that without using that syntax? If so, how?

Comment: You want to get all parameters from a JSP page.  You know `request.getParameters()` does it.  Why look for a different solution?

Comment: JSPs are generally considered gauche nowadays, iiuc.  Normally they're only found in (very old) legacy apps.  It's fine to learn but if this is new code that will actually be released, please use something more modern.

Comment: Because i have a assignment  to look into it . My mentor said i should know deeper before learning Spring MVC.

Comment: You shouldn't deal with parameters in JSPs in the first place. JSPs are the V in MVC. Thei only job should be to generate HTML based on a model (Java beans) stored in the request by the controller. The controller, written in Java, should be the one dealing with the input from the user, i.e. the parameters.